# Best Camera setup for iPad Demonstration

Tags: ipad, video, camera, projector

need to do a live demo of an ipad app to be shown on a projector.  tried using a flip cam but there is a ton of reflection / glare.  i've seen folks put the ipad on what looks like an overhead projector with a camera attached to the top, so the ipad sits flat on the table area and the camera is on an arm above it pointing down.

anyone know what this setup is or what type of camera is used and where to get it?

thanks!

Comment: Sorry, that nothing to do with Apple software or hardware, you can replace the iPad with any electronic device. Voting to close.

Comment: where on stack exchange would be the best place to post this question?

Comment: that's the thing, there's not really a site for this kind of question. You best chance is to wait for this question to be answered (it's not closed yet, it needs 4 more user to vote on it) or to hang out in [chat] and hope somebody will know how to answer there.

Comment: I'm closing this because, as @LoïcWolff said, it isn't really on topic. I'd suggest looking into a way to connect the iPad directly to the projector, which would be on topic for this site. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/ is a great place to look for specifics on how the pros do it. Google Peter Belanger as well - he's known for doing stunning Apple Product shots. For regular folks, get a polarizing filter and the flip or any camera will do a much better job.

Comment: I know the question was closed, but take a look at http://www.ipevo.com/prods/Point-2-View-USB-Camera .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to soft your light source by using light softener or light diffusor. It either can be bought in photo store or [you can DIY](http://www.ehow.com/video_2370062_light-diffusion-video-production.html).

And second, antiglare film over iPad screen will add to a better picture.